# I have got some lights for hydroponic growing, they run from the UK mains but have small clover shaped connectors - what are these called?

Tags: electricity, light

I just got a load of LED grow light tubes - they have mains connectors that use clover shaped plugs -- very much like a lot of laptop chargers use, but just a bit smaller.

There is no label on the plugs, does anyone know what their name/id is so I can get some longer leads?

Comment: Can you provide a picture or a link to the listing where you bought them?

Comment: @LShaver thanks for taking the time to respond - I tracked them down (answer added)... My microgreens are going to be very happy... I just need to monitor the power consumption so I can then work out how many solar panels I'll need to run them.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently they are specialist lighting plugs (sheesh, yet another 'standard'!) and generally referred to as T5 or T8 connectors. T5 and T8 actually being a reference to the size/diameter of old school florescent tubes(!).

I chopped the end off a different old lead, and soldered the wires into the end of connector like the one in the pic, and finished it with electrical tape!

[image]

I hadn't found them because I was looking at the 'C' series of connectors (C5 being the 'mickey mouse' connector that is very similar, very, very common - but bigger...)
[image]